# How to mock HttpClient in a provided service in a component test in Angular?

Tags: angular, unit-testing

Let's say I have a service that makes use of HttpClient,

```js
@Injectable()
export class MyService {
  constructor(protected httpClient: HttpClient) { .. }
}
```

And then a component that makes use of this service.

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-component'
})

export class SendSmsComponent {
  constructor(private MyService) { .. }
}
```

How to test this component while mocking the HttpClient and not the whole service?

```js
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [MyComponent],
  providers: [
    { provide: MyService, useClass: MyService } // ?
  ]
}).compileComponents();

httpMock = TestBed.get(HttpTestingController); // ?
```

Comment: Considering that this is unit test, the proper way to do this is to mock the entire service.

Comment: and looking to this story in so helpful(walk before running)
https://dev.to/zaklaughton/the-only-3-steps-you-need-to-mock-an-api-call-in-jest-39mb

Answer (score 34):

To mock HttpClient you can use [HttpClientTestingModule](https://angular.io/api/common/http/testing/HttpClientTestingModule) with [HttpTestingController](https://angular.io/api/common/http/testing/HttpTestingController)

Sample code to accomplish the same

```js
import { TestBed, ComponentFixture } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { Type } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientTestingModule, HttpTestingController } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import { SendSmsComponent } from './send-sms/send-sms.component';
import { ApiService } from '@services/api.service';

describe('SendSmsComponent ', () => {
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<SendSmsComponent>;
  let app: SendSmsComponent;
  let httpMock: HttpTestingController;

  describe('SendSmsComponent ', () => {
    beforeEach(async () => {
      TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [
          HttpClientTestingModule,
        ],
        declarations: [
          SendSmsComponent,
        ],
        providers: [
          ApiService,
        ],
      });

      await TestBed.compileComponents();

      fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SendSmsComponent);
      app = fixture.componentInstance;
      httpMock = fixture.debugElement.injector.get<HttpTestingController>(HttpTestingController as Type<HttpTestingController>);

      fixture.detectChanges();
    });

    afterEach(() => {
      httpMock.verify();
    });

    it('test your http call', () => {
      const dummyUsers = [
        { name: 'John' },
      ];

      app.getUsers();
      const req = httpMock.expectOne(`${url}/users`);
      req.flush(dummyUsers);

      expect(req.request.method).toBe('GET');
      expect(app.users).toEqual(dummyUsers);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Is all this code really necessary to mock HttpClient? Looks like a copy-past from your project code base. Where exactly does the magic happen? Some explanations would be useful.

Answer (score 18):

This is the approach I follow while testing `HttpClient`

1. Create mock `HttpClient` object

   ```js
   const httpClientSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('HttpClient', ['post', 'get']);
   ```
2. Injecting mock object in `providers`

   ```js
   providers: [{ provide: HttpClient, useValue: httpClientSpy }]
   ```
3. Return dummy valued within `beforeEach()` or `it()`

   ```js
   httpClientSpy.post.and.returnValue(of({ status: 200, data: {} }));
   httpClientSpy.get.and.returnValue(of({ status: 200, data: {} }));
   ```
4. Example test case

   ```js
   it('should return data for abc endpoint', () => {
     service.methodWithHttpRequest().subscribe(data => expect(data.status).toBe(200));
   });
   ```

Comment: and how to call httpClientSpy get method?