# Testing a service with a dependancy that wraps the httpClient methods

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I am trying to test a service that performs a http call to a BE returning data. The problem I am having is that there is another service provided via DI that wraps the httpClient calls for each method on the service I wish to test.

**Service I am trying to test**

```
getValueByUuid(uuid: string): Observable<Value> {
        return this._apiService.get<Value>(`${this.endpoint}/${uuid}/`);
    }
```

We have created another service that wraps the standard REST methods (get, post, patch, delete) with httpClient, allowing us to modify these requests in just one place.

**HttpClient Wrapper** (_apiService referenced above)

```
get<T>(url: string, options?: {}): Observable<T> {
        return this.http
            .get(`${this.apiEndpoint}/${url}`, {...options})
            .pipe(catchError(this.processError.bind(this)));
    }
```

I have attempted to mock this request so that I can create the test, but am unsure how best to do this due to the httpClient being in the mocked dependancy.

**Current Attempt**

```
    let service: ValueService;
    let apiServiceSpy: jasmine.SpyObj<ApiService>;
    let httpTestingController: HttpTestingController;

    beforeEach(() => {
        apiServiceSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('ApiService', ['get', 'post', 'put', 'delete']);
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
            providers: [
                { provide: ApiService, useValue: apiServiceSpy },
                ValueService
            ]
        });
        service = TestBed.inject(ValueService);
        httpTestingController = TestBed.inject(HttpTestingController);
    });
    

    it('#getValueByUuid should return a value for a given uuid', () => {
        let uuid= "1"
        service.getValue(uuid).subscribe(
            (res) => {
                expect(res).toBeTruthy();
                expect(res).toBe(TEST_VALUES[uuid])
            }
        )
        const req = httpTestingController.expectOne(req => req.url === `/value/${uuid}`);
        expect(req.request.method).toEqual('GET');
        req.flush({results: TEST_VALUES[uuid]})
    });
```

**Error**
I am currently getting the following error from this approach -
`Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined`

The only articles I have been able to find use HttpClient directly on the service they are testing and as such don't have this problem.

Am I going about this in the correct manner? Should I be looking to mock some kind of observable response for each of the tests for the "get, post, ...etc" and if so how would I go about doing this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: you may need to mock entire HttpClientModule, did you try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46930581/how-to-mock-httpclient-in-a-provided-service-in-a-component-test-in-angular)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you're mocking `ApiService` but then providing the test implementation of `HttpClient` that the real `ApiService` requires and not the mock.

I would keep `ApiService` mocked and do something like this:

```
    let service: ValueService;
    let apiServiceSpy: jasmine.SpyObj<ApiService>;
    // !! Get rid of this line !!
    // let httpTestingController: HttpTestingController;

    beforeEach(() => {
        apiServiceSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('ApiService', ['get', 'post', 'put', 'delete']);
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            // !! don't import HttpClientTestingModule
            // imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
            providers: [
                { provide: ApiService, useValue: apiServiceSpy },
                ValueService
            ]
        });
        service = TestBed.inject(ValueService);
        // !! get rid of this line
        // httpTestingController = TestBed.inject(HttpTestingController);
    });
    

    it('#getValueByUuid should return a value for a given uuid', (done: DoneFn) => {
        apiServiceSpy.get.and.returnValue(of({ results: TEST_VALUES[uuid] }));
        let uuid= "1"
        service.getValue(uuid).subscribe(
            (res) => {
                expect(res).toBeTruthy();
                // see your result
                console.log({ res });
                done();
            }
        );
    });
```

Comment: Thank you this makes sense & then I can unit test the API service in isolation using HttpTestingController. I was trying to do too much in one place!